# Bootstrap duallistbox can't submit (bad request)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, listbox, multi-select

I am using bootstrap duallistbox to make a multiselect in my site. I am working with spring mvc. The problem is recieve a bad request response when I try to post my selections. Here is my select tag structure:

```
 <select multiple="multiple" name="selectedUsers" id="selectedUsers" class="form-control">
        <c:forEach items="${allUsers}" var="item">
          <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${fn:contains(selectedUsersList, item.id.toString())}">
            <option value="${item.id}" selected>${item.username}</option>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
              <option value="${item.id}">${item.username}</option>
            </c:otherwise>
          </c:choose>
          </c:forEach>
      </select>
```

The data being posted is: 
    profileType=0&selectedUsers=4444444&selectedUsers=aaaaaa&selectedUsers=893247
&_selectedUsers=1

As you may see I am recieving selectedUsers but not in the correct manner for the bind to happen.

Can anyone guide me on how to make this work?
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, The problem was I was expecting a List of Integers in selectedUsers, while some of the id-s I was selecting were in fact string. I changed my List to List and worked with strings instead of integers